# Binary Logistic Loss in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any implemented "**binary logistic loss**" in Tensorflow?
I found the following definition for implementing it:

```
loss(x, y) = log(1 + exp(-x))        if y == 1
             log(1 + exp(-x)) + x    if y == 0
```

I wanted to check if it's the best way to do it if it's not already there:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(1 + tf.exp(-x)) + tf.abs(y - 1) *x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out tf.equal() (returns a bool) and then feed the resulting bool into tf.select()